# cursor in Brackets

Tags: html

I am having trouble with the Brackets program used for HTML editing, beforehand I want to specify (yes I have looked online/on Brackets website and everywhere else) I am new to Brackets. Now, for the problem. I am typing the code, and if I see I have made a mistake and go back to edit it, the cursor is really odd and instead of backspacing and inserting the character, it will replace the character nearest ahead of it. Example: I type tio (instead of two). I backspace the I so I will have "to" and when I type the 'w' in between the 't' and the 'o', it replaces the 'o' and it turns into 'tw'.. help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you have pressed the 'insert' key on your keyboard...if so, press it again to get your normal cursor function back

Comment: No problem...:) God speed - (don't forget to tick the question has been answered)